# How to use prepared statements in Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, prepared-statement

Mysql supports prepared statements in this way:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Is there a support for it in Zend Framework (I couldn't find it), and how to use it. If not, how would you implement prepared statements as Zend Framework addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I didn't find ZF's support for prepared statements in this very same way. The only thing you can do is to emulate it as @Nikita Gopkalo posted.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = :id ";

$stmt  = Zend_Registry::get("db")->prepare($sql);

$data=array(array('id'=> $id);

$stmt->execute($data);

print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = :id'";
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($this->_db, $sql); 
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

Comment: does it really work like this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html or is it just an emulation?

Comment: You can't reuse this very same statement in next request, without re-creating it, so it doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the zend documentation.

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/doc/book/result-set.md

so here is a sample code.

```
<?php

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;

$statement = $driver->createStatement('SELECT * FROM users');
$statement->prepare();
$result = $statement->execute($parameters);

if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult()) {
  $resultSet = new ResultSet;
  $resultSet->initialize($result);

  foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
    echo $row->my_column . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

?>
```