# How to use prepared statements in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I founded this interesting post on how to use prepared statement in zend framework 1

[How to use prepared statements in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104093/how-to-use-prepared-statements-in-zend-framework)

I want to do the same thing in Zend Framework 2

something like

```
$sql = "UPDATE foo set bar = :value where id = :id"
$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->queryPrepareStatement($sql, array('value' => 'some value', 'id' => 123)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a easy way to do it using the tableGateway

```
$sql = "UPDATE foo set bar = :value where id = :id"
$data = array('value' => 'some value', 'id' => 123)

$stmt = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->createStatement($sql);
$stmt->prepare($sql);
return $stmt->execute($data);
```